# 14.04 Keyboard and Mouse not working in Recovery and Login

Tags: 14.04, boot, keyboard

Good day to everyone. So I'm still somewhat new to this and have been learning with each problem I encounter, but this one I can't seem to wrap my head around as and it is why I am here.

So this all started with that most recent libnl-3 update that occurred and crashed or stalled out most peoples network managers about a week ago. I understand I had proposed checked, stupid me, anyway I tried to downgrade those files (libnl, libnl-route and libnl-gen) anyway things were looking good. Until I restarted my computer. Not my keyboard will not work at the main log in screen, nor in recovery mode no matter which kernel I choose to use.

I have been able to make a live usb, and boot it in Legacy OS mode (as opposed to uefi (?) which nothing happens in.)

Anyway I guess im asking is there anyway to use a live usb to some how update my current messed up kernel.

I am running 14.04 uh I'm not sure what more information provide so please forgive me, but I can always update with needed information. Thank you so much for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can still use your mouse why not try reinstalling/installing input device drivers?

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-input-all
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all
```

Comment: my mistake i forgot to list my mouse is not working as well, it does come on but does not move around the screen.

Comment: also i can't get past the login screen.

Comment: Any chance USB Legacy Support is disabled in the BIOS setup?